# Calculating curl

Tags: vectors

I need help with the following question:

Let C be the curve $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ lying in the plane $z = 1$. Let $F = (z - y)i + yk$.

How do you calculate the divergence $∇$ x $F$?

Comment: Did you notice that "divergence ∇ x F" is problematic? Because $\nabla \times$ is the curl operation not the divergence.

Comment: Oh my bad, so what will the answer be for this?

Comment: I gave you both divergence and curl. You can pick. I also gave a recommendation. What else can I do?

Comment: Ok so the curl is (1,1,1)

Answer (score 1):

The divergence of $F$ is
$$
\mbox{div } F = \nabla \cdot F = \sum_i \partial_i F_i
$$
where
$$
\partial_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}
$$

The curl ("rotation") of $F$ is
$$
\mbox{curl } F
= \mbox{rot } F 
= \nabla \times F 
= \sum_{i,j,k} \epsilon_{ijk} \, e_i \, \partial_j F_k 
= \mbox{det}(e, \nabla, F) 
$$
where $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the Levi-Civita tensor (if $(i,j,k)$ is a permutation it is the sign of that permutation, otherwise it is $0$) and $e_i$ is the $i$-th canonical base vector.

Considering that a curve is given as well, I guess you need to calculate the curl.
$$
\left|
\begin{matrix}
e_1 & e_2 & e_3 \\
\partial_1 & \partial_2 & \partial_3 \\
z-y & 0 & y
\end{matrix}
\right|
=
(1,1,1)
$$

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: I evaluated the determinant for you.

Comment: Is that the final answer?

Comment: Do you have any clue why a curve $C$ might have something to do with the curl of a vector field?

Comment: No im not quiete sure

Comment: There are famous integral theorems connected to the differential operators grad, div, curl. Have a look there.